# Does wicket tree work for "not direct" children?

Tags: java, listview, wicket, treetable

Hey I have following situation:

**Class Foo** has a List of **Foos**, 
Every **Foo** contains one or more Objects of the Class **Bar** and has therefore a List **Bars**. 
Every **Bar** has one or more Objects of **Qux**, which is another class and because of that is safed in a List named **Quxs**.

Is it even possible to loop through these Lists / Sets with a Wicket *TableTree*, *TreeTable*, *DefaultTreeTable* or whatever else.

Right now I'm trying to solve this with 3 nested *ListViews*, which seems not to be the best solution.
Because if you have to use a ListView, whitin a ListView of ListView, it is difficult to get the Object you are refering to.

Answer (score 3):

The decision whether to use ListViews or one of the Tree components should really be made based on the desired look&feel (ie. possible user interactions like opening/closing nodes in a tree). It is definitely possible to present your nested list with its three different classes in a tree (though you may not be able to take advantage of Java generics in this case, unless all the classes have some suitable common interface).

The ITreeProvider interface is a good place to start, if you want to build your own tree structure (https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/7.x/org/apache/wicket/extensions/markup/html/repeater/tree/ITreeProvider.html).